# lambda functionality taking too much to read file and create bean + java 8

Tags: java, java-8, javabeans, java-7

i am trying to read CSV file and creating bean object using java.
 I have one constraint where we are having list of objects in LeadStg object  name as customAnswersStgs which i am dynamically adding into this file . 
As i am using JAVA 8 so i am using lambda functionality  ,  but response of below code is time consuming i want help on this to minimise response time of below code.
Can somebody quickly help on this, as it is acting as a bottleneck. Thanks in advance.

```
private List<LeadStg> processInputFile(String inputFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<LeadStgRequest> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<LeadStg> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        File inputF = new File(inputFilePath);
        InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(inputF);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS, "ISO-8859-1"));
        inputList = br.lines().skip(1).map(mapToLeadStg).collect(Collectors.toList());
        br.close();
        inputFS.close();

        for (LeadStgRequest obj : inputList) {
            ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
            LeadStg value = modelMapper.map(obj, LeadStg.class);
            outputList.add(value);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return outputList;
}

private Function<String, LeadStgRequest> mapToLeadStg = (line) -> {
    List<CustomAnswersStg> customAnswersStgs = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    String[] p = line.split(",");
    LeadStgRequest leadStgReq = new LeadStgRequest(Integer.parseInt(p[count++]), p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++],
            p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++], p[count++]);
    if (header.contains(COMMENTS))
        leadStgReq.setComments(p[count++]);
    List<String> res = header.stream().filter(k -> k.startsWith(CUSTOM)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!res.isEmpty()) {
        customAnswersStgs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= res.size(); i++) {
            CustomAnswersStg cas = new CustomAnswersStg();
            cas.setQuestionNumber(i);
            cas.setAnswer(p.length > count ? p[count++] : "");
            customAnswersStgs.add(cas);
        }
        leadStgReq.setCustomAnswersStgs(customAnswersStgs);
    }
    return leadStgReq;
};
```

Comment: Well, reading a file does take some time. How big is your file and what is your runtime?

Comment: Hi @AndréStannek i have 2oo row in file and time is taking around 1 min. and column i have only "Campaign Id,Company Name,First Name,Last Name,Title,Email,Work Phone,Street,City,State,Zip Code,Country,Company Employees,Company Revenue,Industry,Asset Name ,Custom1,Custom2 ,Custom3, Custom4"

Comment: Where is your bottleneck exactly?

Comment: @AnandKumar this could be normal. Where is your `header` variable comming from?

Comment: @AnandKumar I think IO is not your bottleneck. Try to instantiate the `ModelMapper` once outside the loop.

Comment: You should learn about the [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html). Besides that, it’s easy to rewrite that lambda part to an ordinary loop, as your are not really using the stream functionality. Then you can check how much lambdas are to blame…

Comment: Thanks @Flown  now response time to fast after modelMapper outside the loop.. thanks for your quick response..